# How can I read a date series of quarterly data into R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset, the first column of which is the date in the format Year-Quarter, like the following

```
 1959-I   
 1959-II   
 1959-III   
 1959-IV    
 1960-I   
 1960-II   
 1960-III   
 1960-IV
```

I have imported the dataset into R, but I don't know how to convert this to `Date` format using the `as.Date` function, since [there doesn't appear to be a conversion specification for quarters](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/strptime.html) and I have just started learning R.

The best I can think of is something like

```
#extract the year
> dates <- substring(data$X,1,4)
> dates[1:8]
[1] "1959" "1959" "1959" "1959" "1960" "1960" "1960" "1960"
> dates <- as.numeric(dates)

#extract the quarter
> quarters <- substring(data$X,6)
> quarters[1:10]
[1] "I "   "II "  "III " "IV "  "I "   "II "  "III " "IV "
```

but this cannot possibly be the best way of doing this, and it still leaves me the problem of how to deal with my series `quarters`. To make matters worse, there is a blank character at the end of each character I don't know how to deal with because there are 3 different "lenghts" for the quarters strings.

Another option, of course, would be to fabricate my own quarters series, with something like

```
quarters <- rep(c(1,2,3,4),dates[length(dates)]-dates[1])
```

(I am quite proud of myself for having written this last line!).

**So my question:** is there a built-in way to import quarterly data in the format I have in R, and if not, any other format (still for quarterly data)? Any suggestions on the best way to proceed?

Comment: Would it be sufficient to assign a date to each quarter value? i.e. `I = 01/01, II = 04/01, III = 07/01, IV = 10/01` or something similar?

Comment: @Chase, what I am really wondering is whether R recognises quarterly data, the same way it recognises years, months, etc. If not, then I will have to do something else, and your suggestion is definitely an option (but surely R, a statistical package, so well developed, would have a built-in alternative?)

Comment: I can give you a ready made solution going down the first path, but you are most likely right re: built in alternative. It looks like `ts` objects support quarterly data via the `frequency = 4` parameter. You may also want to look at the [CRAN Task View for Time Sieres](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html). From what I'm seen, packages zoo and xts are also pretty robust and flexible, so they may have something rolled up. I bet someone will come along soon and show us something all fancylike.

Comment: @Chase I have not been able to install the package "ts" because it doesn't appear to be available for R version 2.14 (I checked a few mirrors, but not all). I tried again just now, and still couldn't do it. I will see if zoo or xts have something

Comment: `ts` is not a package in itself, it's part of the `stats` package which is loaded by default. You should be able to type `?ts` to check out the help page. THe examples have an example of quarterly data.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Suppose we have data 1:8 which corresponds to the 8 quarters you mention.  Then we can do this:

```
ts(1:8, start = c(1959, 1), frequency = 4)
##      Qtr1 Qtr2 Qtr3 Qtr4
## 1959    1    2    3    4
## 1960    5    6    7    8
```

Also the zoo package has the `"yearqtr"` class:

```
 library(zoo)

 z <- zooreg(1:8, start = as.yearqtr("1959-1"), frequency = 4)
 z
 ## 1959 Q1 1959 Q2 1959 Q3 1959 Q4 1960 Q1 1960 Q2 1960 Q3 1960 Q4 
 ##       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8
```

If we really did have a vector of such quarters that are not necessarily consecutive:

```
dt <- c("1959-I", "1959-II", "1959-III", "1959-IV", "1960-I", "1960-II", 
      "1960-III", "1960-IV")
```

we could convert them using `gsubfn`:

```
library(gsubfn)

g <- gsubfn("I.*", list(`I` = 1, `II` = 2, `III` = 3, `IV` = 4), dt)
g
## [1] "1959-1" "1959-2" "1959-3" "1959-4" "1960-1" "1960-2" "1960-3" "1960-4"

as.yearqtr(g)
## [1] "1959 Q1" "1959 Q2" "1959 Q3" "1959 Q4" "1960 Q1" "1960 Q2" "1960 Q3"
## [8] "1960 Q4"
```